# Attach audio files together to question ... Absurd or creative?

Tags: discussion

I believe that this question will seem absurd or even off-topic, but anyway.

Imagine a colleague who has a "relatively extensive" question to be written and even understood. This will become boring and unattractive.

Let us suppose that this question is written in a simplified and summarized way, with the aim of presenting only one introduction to the problem.

The written question would be to maintain the existing pattern in this community, but in an introductory way only. Even not being very clear to anyone who wants to respond because it is very complex.

But for those who feel a certain interest in responding there could be a link where there is an audio file where the OP asks your question in much more detail, being even more dynamic and pleasant because it is an audio where it is possible to identify important details that could be forgotten if they were written.

The idea is simple. There is a simplified written question for general users and an attached audio for users who are really willing to help with the problem.

I hope I have been clear. If it was not clear, I'll attach an audio to explain better ...

Answer (score 5):

This is one of the more unusual questions I've seen asked, and for that reason if none other I find it interesting. :-)  Nevertheless what you propose does not seem like a good fit for Stack Exchange.

1. Posts should ideally be stand-alone content, not dependent on external links or data files.  Repeatedly I have seen questions reliant on external data become meaningless when that data becomes unavailable, sometimes "stranding" good answers without context.
2. A spoken presentation should be translatable to written word.  Writing is a well established art at this point in human history and it should not be difficult to convey ideas in this medium.  It seems to me that any literate person who can craft a dynamic and interesting spoken presentation should also be able write one of acceptable quality.  Further the site software provides a variety of formatting tools to visually support different styles and needs.
3. Written word can be translated automatically, making a question (and its answers) accessible to a wider audience.  I do not believe free audio computer translations are readily available in the same manner.
4. Even if translation to a different language is not required written word may be easier to understand due to significant differences in pronunciation or dialect.  It is not uncommon to see e.g. English subtitles applied to Asians or Europeans speaking English with a thick accent.

In my opinion it is therefore undesirable to enact what you describe.  I could perhaps see the occasional merit of asking a question in a video presentation as there are things that are otherwise difficult to illustrate I think, but I have doubt that anything complex enough to really require that belongs on this site.

There are other Stack Exchange (engine) sites that are far more technical such as [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) and [PhysicsOverflow](https://physicsoverflow.org/) and while I do not follow either site closely a cursory viewing does not suggest that such things are common there.  If such matter can be adequately addressed in the illustrated written medium I suspect that our content can as well.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Your arguments are very good.

Comment: I agree with you. I myself do not speak English. The question was created to explore other possibilities of communication depending on the feedbacks that arise.