# Is it possible to append a file to a question on mathematica stackexchange?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible  to append a file to a question  on  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: Yes, example here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/264684/363. In this case demo files are zipped and embedded in an image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload large amount of data more easily](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/upload-large-amount-of-data-more-easily)

Comment: This question has been [asked and answered before](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1351/10397) . In any case, you should, in most cases, avoid large data or code, by providing a minimum working example, with code that generates simple synthetic data, if necessary. If inevitable to share the data, the method should be permanent, safe and easy to retrieve.

Comment: There are always services like pastebin.com....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the notebook thusly

```
extractNB[file_String] := Uncompress@Last@
   StringSplit[URLFetch@file, "Embedded data:"]

writeNB[png_String, nb_String] := Module[{},
  outputstream = OpenWrite[
    FileNameJoin[{$InitialDirectory, nb}],
    BinaryFormat -> True];
  BinaryWrite[outputstream, extractNB@png];
  Close[outputstream]]

writeNB["https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eeTp.png",
 "retrieved notebook.nb"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Doing this is technically possible by "misuing" SE's image hosting, as Chris's answer shows.  However, my opinion on this topic is that you just shouldn't try attach notebooks.

Part of what makes SE's QA format work is that questions must fit into limited space. This forces the asker to do their part of the work: minimize their code+data example, explain the issue concisely, be on point and focus on a single issue. I believe that in the great majority of cases attachments are not necessary, and would make the question problematic (less clear, less easily answerable).

If you search meta, you will find similar opinions being expressed:

- [How to attach a notebook to a question?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1863/12)
- [What's the appropriate method to share notebooks and packages in this community?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2690/12)
- [Attach audio files together to question ... Absurd or creative?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2175/12)